# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function when using a jQuery plugin in Magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I am working on a Magento Extension.  Magento has a known issue when you try to use jQuery in Magento because Magento uses the Prototype library.

The work around for it is to put your jQuery code in no conflict mode like this...

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Once I did this, it resolved 90% of my problems i was having with JavaScript errors.  However I still have 3 major problems with JavaScript right now and I believe they are related...

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

http://www.codedevelopr.com/screenshots/2014/2014-08-23_16-14-37.png

When I view the line numbers that it is reporting these errors from I see this...

[image]

Line 1168 `jQuery(".acc-wizard").accwizard({` now this `accwizard()` is a function that is loaded from a jQuery plugin file.  I have verified the file is loaded and it is loaded after my jQuery and after I set the no conflict mode for jQuery.  I am not sure if something in the plugin file needs to be changed as well to work with the no conflict mode or why it is saying it is undefine?

Same situation with `simplecolorpicker()` on line 1180.

I have uploaded the file that holds the `accwizard()` jQuery Plugin, it is about 14kb in size and can be found here http://www.codedevelopr.com/screenshots/2014/acc-wizard-bs-3.js I figured it is a little to large to post that code here.

Can anyone help me to get these errors resolved?  It seems any jQuery plugin I try to use results in this undefined error above?

---

**UPDATE**

So I have been experimenting with a lot of things with no luck...that is until I tried loading all my JS files inline in my actual template page that my extension uses...once I do that, it all works with none of these errors.

This is frustrating though as I much prefer to have separate JS file for my JS...instead of loading 3 JS files I even tried putting all 3 into 1 file and loading that 1 file but I still get the JS errors...now when I copy that 1 file that had all 3 files combined and put it directly in the template file...everything works perfectly! This makes no sense to me, please help?

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough context in your answer to pinpoint the reason, but it sounds like your web browser executes the code ...

```
jQuery('foo').accwizard
```

**BEFORE** it has downloaded and initialized the plugin that defines the `accwizard` method.